# position:fixed not being appended in ie

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to make a menu have a fixed position when it hits the top of the screen.

Something like this works fine across Chrome, Safari and Firefox but can't seem to get it work in IE.

```
var oritop = -100;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollt = window.scrollY;
    var elm = $(".box");
    if(oritop < 0) {
        oritop= elm.offset().top;
    }
    if(scrollt >= oritop) {
        elm.css({"position": "fixed", "top": 0, "left": 0});
    }
    else {
        elm.css("position", "static");
    }
});
```

I can't even get the fiddle to work in IE - http://jsfiddle.net/glee/yLRVZ/

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Have you look [jQuery scrolltofixed](http://bigspotteddog.github.io/ScrollToFixed/) ?

Comment: scrollY is not supported in all browsers -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollY

Comment: "For cross-browser compatibility, use window.pageYOffset instead of window.scrollY." Try using a breakpoint or console.log to inspect the variable scrollt. You'll see that is undefined.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yLRVZ/153/

Comment: @adeneo I think you should add those two comments as an answer

Comment: @Mathias - New user asking a question, and no response to the comments. Most of the time they just figure it out and leave without giving any feedback as to wether or not they figured it out, but thanks!

Comment: @adeneo Stack Overflow is so useful hence I rarely find myself needing to ask a question, but on this instance i'd run out of options. I do appreciate the answers too and was always intent on returning to leave feedback, but give a man a chance - it's not been long since I asked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing `window.scrollY` to `$(this).scrollTop()`

http://jsfiddle.net/yLRVZ/154